Does this sentence "My friend got a call from me to ask her to go camping" make sense?
Are these sentences more or less the same?
1-"I called my friend to ask her to go camping"
2-"I gave my friend a call to ask her to go camping"
3-"My friend got a call from me to ask her to go camping"
I think (1) and (2) are roughly the same. But the (3) is strange.
There is a quiz
Given this sentence "I gave my friend a call to ask her to go camping"
Please complete this sentence "My friend got a call from me ......" so that it is the same as the above one.

A question whether the statement "makes sense" requires an actual context since "makes sense" normally means more than "is intelligible" and includes whether the statement is idiomatic in context.  We wouldn't normally say, for example, "At dinner, the food is chewed by me carefully" or "When the light turns green, the street is crossed by me."

Your thoughts are more or less correct here.
The first one is natural and expected.
The second is possible, and would certainly have the same meaning, but it's a subtly odd collocation. "Giving a call" usually means the intention is to chat, to catch up, etc., so adding a functional motivation to it sounds odd. A more natural pairing: "I gave my friend a call to cheer her up."
The third one is indeed bizarre, though again it would have to mean the same thing. What makes it strange is that the construction strongly suggests that the caller is unknown to you or your friend and thus can't be phrased as the subject of the sentence ("got a call from an unknown number") or that the call was of some official nature, was part of a protocol of some kind ("got a call from the principal / the CRA"). Obviously, when you're the caller and the call is to ask to go camping, these expectations are thwarted.
But if that's what the quiz expects, I guess it'll have to get an answer from you to provide the bizarre sentence as you wrote it...
